# Customizing labels in bar graph with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I've looked at several answers online, and can't seem to get what I want. Here's a sample data frame and plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Abbreviation': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 'Score 1': [1, 2, 3, 4.5, 6, None, None], 'w1': [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 6.5, None, None], 'Score 2': [None, None, 1.6, 3.5, 7.2, 3.4, 5.8], 'w2': [None, None, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]})

ax = df.plot(x = 'Abbreviation', y = ['w1', 'w2'], kind = 'barh')
```

How would I provide annotations using *only* the "Score 1" column of my data frame? So in the example plot, this would annotate only the data associated with w1.

I've tried variations on this:

```
for p in ax.patches:
  ax.annotate(("%.2f" % p.get_width(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width(), p.get_y()), xytext=(5, 10), textcoords='offset points')
```

But where I get stuck is the where I provide ax.annotate with the list of text I want to use (the data contained in column "Score 1").

I've also tried variations on this as well:

```
for (x, y, z) in zip(df['Abbreviation'], df['w1'], df['Score 1']):
  ax.annotate('{:.0f}'.format(z), xy = (x,y,), xytext=(5, 10), textcoords='offset points')
```

But this throws an error because I'm passing a bunch of letters to the x coordinates.

I feel like the solution must be much simpler than I'm trying to make it. What am I missing?

Comment: what are you going to do with NaN's?

Comment: I'd prefer to leave them blank (not provide an annotation for any NaN value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ax = df.plot(x = 'Abbreviation', y = ['w1', 'w2'], kind = 'barh')

for i,p in enumerate(ax.patches):
    if i >= len(df):
        break
    if df.at[df.index[i], 'Score 1']:
        ax.annotate(df.fillna('').at[df.index[i], 'Score 1'], 
                    (p.get_x() + p.get_width(), p.get_y()),
                    xytext=(5, 10), 
                    textcoords='offset points')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Two things, though: when I try to recreate this, I get an "index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7." Also, I'm looking to essentially annotate all of the blue bars, and it looks like there's some data missing from the graph you've posted (Abbreviations 'b' and 'd' also have data for 'Score 1').

Comment: The edit works beautifully! This was incredibly helpful (and gave me some additional understanding of the ax.annotate portion of what I'm trying to do). I really appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: @kknight, glad i could help :)